# C# tab order with radio buttons

Tags: c#, tab-ordering

SO i have a windows form application, there is a textbox which tells you what grocery item you want to select. There are 3 radio buttons answers which you can chose from and a button that submits that answer. What i want is to be able to navigate through those radio buttons using tab . I have tried the tab order thing but it doesnt work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why won't you use Dropdown List instead? Sounds more fitting.

Comment: You can trap the tab key in a KeyPress event and handle it yourself. Or inherit from the radio button class and extend it to handle tab key presses.

Comment: This is the default behavior of radio button. If you want to change it, you might need to subclass it and re-implement the keyboard behavior. Or - may be, you might create a radio button of your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windws Forms lets you only Tab into the group. One way to hack around it is to get all Buttons in seperate Groups by putting group boxes around each one of them.

Although this allows you to tab through them, they are now disjointed and will not automatically deselect. To do so register for the event that fires on selection and deselect the others programatically.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        private List<RadioButton> allMyButtons;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            allMyButtons = new List<RadioButton>
            {
                radioButton1,
                radioButton2
            };
        }

        private void radioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RadioButton sendingRadio = (sender as RadioButton);
            if(sendingRadio == null) return;
            if(sendingRadio.Checked == true){
                foreach(var rb in (from b in allMyButtons where b != sendingRadio select b))
                {
                    rb.Checked = false;
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I tested this approach and it seems to do the job.

Forms is not the modern way of doing things. Consider moving to WPF for new Projects.