# Radio Buttons not passing tab order as expected

Tags: winforms, .net-3.5, radio-button, tab-ordering

I have a group box containing 4 radio buttons and then 10 regular button. I have Visual Studio's "Tab Order" view enabled here in the screenshot below:

[image]

When I run the application and try to tab over everything, the GroupBox (3) gets focus, press Tab, 3.0 (Radio Button #1) gets focus, Press Tab then 4.0 gets focus, 4.1, 4.2 etc.

I tried to search around for a fix, but everything seems to be ASP related.

Comment: This might be a duplicate of `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12758038/c-sharp-tab-order-with-radio-buttons`

Comment: Did you find any fix to this problem?